# Printing to output window in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty new to C++ and recently switched from compiling in g++ on Linux to Visual Studio. I was trying to write a simple program to test some like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    // Things
}
```

And I was using `cout <<` to display what the function returns, before I realized that it doesn't work this way to print to the output window in Visual Studio. I know I can use the debug mode, but is there a way in Visual Studio to display output to the window? One of the older posts that I found suggested using OutputDebugString, but I didn't write the code as Win32 application, and I think this function doesn't exist for simple cpp files.

Also, is there a reason why a black window pops up when the program is executed, and then immediately disappears?

Comment: What exactly is in `//things`? The console shouldn't disappear straight away normally, and `std::cout` should normally print to it.

Comment: @chris yeah that was me not knowing cout would be printed there, and the //things was very short. All I needed to do was to add a breakpoint at the end. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean. For some reason it doesn't wait for you when debugging, but it does when you start without debugging. I'm not quite sure why. While I'm talking I might as well point out that any hosted environment such as Windows expects an integer return value from `main`.

Comment: If your IDE doesn't provide a way to launch console programs with a persistent console, it's junk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OutputDebugString for the win. It does exists. Just include windows.h. It's there.

There are ways to effectively wire stderr and stdout to a pipe and have you resink the output to OutputDebugString, but it sounds like you're looking for a simple way. Anything written to stdout (cout, whatever) will go to the console window, so before you go OutputDebugString nuts check your console window first for your output...

Speaking of console window...

The reason black pops up and immediately disappears is your console window is opening and closing, and chances are your process is finishing before anything substantial is done. Jam a breakpoint at the end of main() in the IDE. You can then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to it.

BTW: if you go with OutputDebugString, it does NOT CRLF the text you send, so include that in your output text.

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize that the outputs would show up in the console window... added a breakpoint and now I can see it. thanks for showing how to use OutputDebugString though!

Answer (score 2):

Below is a portable TRACE macro I have written.

On Windows, it is based on `OutputDebugString` as indicated in  WhozCraig's answer.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_TRACE
#  ifdef _MSC_VER
#    include <windows.h>
#    include <sstream>
#    define TRACE(x)                           \
     do {  std::stringstream s;  s << (x);     \
           OutputDebugString(s.str().c_str()); \
        } while(0)
#  else
#    include <iostream>
#    define TRACE(x)  std::clog << (x)
#  endif        // or std::cerr << (x) << std::flush
#else
#  define TRACE(x)
#endif
```

Example:

```
#define ENABLE_TRACE  // Can depend on _DEBUG or NDEBUG macros
#include "my_above_trace_header.h"

int main (void)
{
   int     v1 = 123;
   double  v2 = 456.789;
   TRACE ("main() v1="<< v1 <<" v2="<< v2 <<'\n');
}
```

Comment: Might want to wrap the macro parameter in parentheses to avoid unintended macro expansion errors.

Comment: Perhaps use `__FUNCTION__` rather than require the caller to provide it. Alternatively I like to integrate `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` into a macro similar when dumping plain debug or error messages. The function is pretty obvious when you open the source file and scroll to the line. Anyway, right idea. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to an output window from within a unittest case then you can use the following:

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

TEST_METHOD(testingsomething)
{
    Logger::WriteMessage("Hello output window");
}
```